# React JS installation using CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, windows-defender

I used the command ' npx create-react-app appname' and it installed react but afterwards when I closed VS code and went to file explorer to view the folder it started to crash. I could not even right click on the folder, I started getting the message ' Folder is not responding' finally I managed to uninstall it, its size was 278MB. Is this normal?
I deleted the folder shortly afterwards. Should I be worried?
I ran a full scan using windows defender it did not show at threats.
Is this just because of CRA decrepated?

Comment: Worried about what?

Comment: I don't know why this happened

Comment: Why VS Code crashed? Don’t know. Restart it.

Comment: It's not VS code that crashed I could open the app folder in file explorer

Comment: File explorer started to crash? What does that even mean? In any case: CRA’s dependencies are around that size; that part seems normal. Your Windows machine crashing does not.

Comment: 278MB is normal for even a bit smaller than expected, that's why there are so many `node_modules` meme around the dev community.

Comment: Well its not like the file explorer closed and I got sent to home screen, the folder were I kept all by web dev stuff which included the react folder refused to open

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.